# Contents in a vertical table-style div arrangement

Tags: css

I have some divs that should take the entire height of a page. I managed to get this working as i needed. (Some fixed rows and some flexible rows) like in a html table.

I took the solution from one of my other questions here:

[Layout divs in css like table cells in HTML Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935011/layout-divs-in-css-like-table-cells-in-html-tables)

Today i had to add a div inside the flexible row which should take 100% of the height of the flexible row. Which works great in all major browsers. Muahaha that was a good joke wasn't it? Of course this doesn't work as expected in IE see my js fiddle:

```
<div class="tableContainer">
<div class="row rowA">
    <div class="cell">Test</div>
</div>
<div class="row rowB">
    <div class="cell">Test</div>
</div>
<div class="row rowC">
    <div class="cell">Test</div>
</div>
<div class="row rowD">
   <div class="cell testcell">
       <div class="testcontent">Test</div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row rowE">
    <div class="cell">Test</div>
</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7ewEJ/3/

the ie seems to take the "100%" from the page and not from the enclosing flexible table row. So the blue div should take the whole space of the purble table row.

- Am i doing anything wrong?
- Could this be a bug in ie's height calculation?

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand how would the answer come? do u have any picture that you want like that?

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/7ewEJ/5/

```
div.testcell{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
min-width: 1px;
min-height: 1px;
/*background: #fff;*/
align: center;
display: block;

}
```

Comment: Sorry that is exactly the opposite of what i need.