# Table like content display using div structure?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Is it possible to display content as shown in attached screenshot using div structure instead table and with html/CSS alone except using jQuery for toggle control.

Few points regarding output:

1. Any child-row and its content won't be visible until user clicks
   arrow-icon of parent-row, clicking same arrow again will hide the
   respective child row.
2. Clicking on arrow-icon will make child row visible using jQuery toggle animation.
3. It has to be responsive.

[image]

Comment: have you tried anything so far??

Comment: but what is the problem with table ?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but it will take up a lot of `<div>`'s. So you might be better off using a table, or build something like this with HTML, CSS and jQuery. Refering to @NoobEditor, have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Using `list` is a better option to replace `table`

Comment: @Saurabh, nothing specific 1. want to check if can be done using div    especially leaving both item-value columns intact from the left side margin/padding of child row. 2. I doubt if jquery toggle will work properly in table.

Comment: @NoobEditor, honestly I didn't but did enough brainstorming looking at structure, then thought to ask here to get any expert advise so could move on in right direction as my first preference is div layout.

Comment: If you only have these concerns then you can definitely work with table. toggle() works on table nicely i have tried. and the indentation has some work but i think it can be achieved. cause working with div's and maintaining them is lot of work. my suggestion try and go with tables.

Comment: @Saurabh, I tried implementing this with table but I'm unable to figure out how to nested child-user-tr inside parent-user-tr. As html doesn't allow another tr inside a tr. And in my case, I (guess) would need tr inside tr show relevant child-user appears only inside respective parent-user, when toggled display-on using arrow on left of parent-user. Right now they all appearing at the same level and not stacked as in design, still thinking with html/css alone. Hope you would have got it!

Comment: tried implementing using ember table way, all fine except toggle animation opening child-elements with some jerk. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ravk/V5zL8/). Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 4):

I guess what you would like to do could be something like this:

**EMBER TABLE**
http://addepar.github.io/#/ember-table/overview

And you can place divs into a table like layout with css `display:table`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="mytable">
    <div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
    </div>   
    <div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
    </div>
<div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.mytable {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

div.mytable > div {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}
div.mytable > div > div {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 20%;
    padding:1em;
}
```

**DEMO**

JSFiddle is here:http://jsfiddle.net/naokiota/jCqm7/3/

And you can read this page:
[Layout divs in css like table cells in HTML Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935011/layout-divs-in-css-like-table-cells-in-html-tables)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried using table attribute as you mentioned above. However the toggle animation opening child-elements with some jerk, could you please see what is causing the issue. Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ravk/V5zL8/)

Comment: @ravk, I took a look at your JSFiddle. I guess I understand what you mean. But could you explain the meaning of 'jerk'? I'm a Japanese and not so good at English. Do you mean that the child-elements are moving unintentionally?

Comment: with jerk I mean that when toggle animation starts to showing up the child-user the row initially expands like jumped to some height directly but then expands with smooth (flow = animation) till exposing rest of the height. The same thing happens when child-user closes down and at the same point of time. Hope it will give you clarity, didn't find any better way to explain it.

Comment: @ravk, Thank you for your answer. I guess it is matter of `.slideTogge()`. I tried to solve this problem, but couldn't find an answer. Instead of using `.slideToggle()`, how about using `.fadeToggle()`. I made a JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/naokiota/6pD8a/1/